# On escape key click make object visible

Tags: unity, c#

I am using the following code which works, But the first time i press escape nothing happens, if i press it again then the game object shows. Does anyone know why this is?

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PauseScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PauseMenu;
    bool Paused = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        PauseMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
        {
            if (Paused == true)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
                PauseMenu.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                Paused = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
                PauseMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                Paused = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the game, you are deactivating your `PauseMenu` and initializing your `Paused` bool to `false`.

The first time you press the escape key, you are following the else path of your if statement and deactivating the `PauseMenu` again, so nothing will appear.

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you simply need to swap your `SetActive(true)` and `SetActive(false)` calls in `Update()`.